# Camera position and angle different when running inside Unity and when running on Android

Tags: unity, android

On Windows, running Unity 4.6.1p5, my simple game with only a cube, camera and light looks like this

[image: windows view]

but under Android (Gingerbread on a 5 inch Galaxy Player) the cube appears lower down, slightly different angle and smaller (relative to the screen size).  Sorry couldn't get a screenshot with my screenshot app...

Any ideas why please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the 2 views were because Unity wasn't updating the Windows build, so it seems to have remained at a different camera position.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is most likely the different *field of view* ([FOV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_view) in general or [specific for Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-fieldOfView.html)) in combination with the aspect ratio of the Android device.

This thread covers the same problem: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/23291/same-visible-area-regardless-of-aspect-ratio.html#

The idea is to calculate the target FOV like this and apply it to the camera:

```
float normalAspect = 16/9f;

myCam.fieldOfView = myDesiredHorizontalFov * normalAspect / ((float)myCam.pixelWidth / myCam.pixelHeight);
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, that's good to know.  Doesn't seem to have been the problem here as it magically resolved itself after restarting Unity. Not sure what is going on, and I hope this isn't to be expected - Unity has already deleted the content of one of my scenes when I upgraded versions...